# How to access Google Drive Shared Content in C# without credential

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have put some folders & files in my Google Drive and already set those items to public shareable.
I would like to write a simple program to list out those folders & files but I'm not sure how to do it.

I know that I have to create a pair of clientId & clientsercet to be a UserCredential and initialize it in DriveService if I want to access my privet google drive.

However, since now the items is already shareable to public, I believe it's possible to access them wihtout any credential? What's the easiest to list and  access those shareable items? Thanks

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/).